# Text extractor php

Tags: php

I have this page [test1.php](http://inviatapenet.gethost.ro/sop/test1.php) on this other page [test.php](http://inviatapenet.gethost.ro/sop/test.php) i have this php code running:

```
 <?php 
    libxml_use_internal_errors(true); 
    $doc = new DOMDocument(); 
    $doc->loadHTMLFile("http://inviatapenet.gethost.ro/sop/test1.php"); 
    $xpath = new DOMXpath($doc); 
    $elements = $xpath->query("//*[@type='text/javascript']/@fid");
        if (!is_null($elements)) {
            foreach ($elements as $element) {
                $nodes = $element->childNodes;
                foreach ($nodes as $node) {
                    echo $node->nodeValue. "\n";
                }
            }
        }
?>
```

But shows nothing.

i'm trying to get from that page, only the content of fid="x8qfp3cvzbxng8e" :

From this Line

```
<script type="text/javascript"> fid="x8qfp3cvzbxng8e"; v_width=640;
v_height=360; </script>
```

The output shold be:

> x8qfp3cvzbxng8e

Wath I have to do?

Comment: don't think /@fid would work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want only `fid` content use this regex

```
 preg_match_all('~fid="(.*?)"~si',$Text,$Match);
 print_r($Match);
```

output for your sample

```
 Array
(
   [0] => Array
    (
        [0] => fid="x8qfp3cvzbxng8e"
    )

   [1] => Array
    (
        [0] => x8qfp3cvzbxng8e
    )

)
```

try this for extract text this not show any `script` content but if you want can remove condition of this

```
 function extractText($node) {
     if($node==NULL)return false;    
     if (XML_TEXT_NODE === $node->nodeType || XML_CDATA_SECTION_NODE === $node->nodeType) {
         return $node->nodeValue;
     } else if (XML_ELEMENT_NODE === $node->nodeType || XML_DOCUMENT_NODE === $node->nodeType || XML_DOCUMENT_FRAG_NODE === $node->nodeType) {
       if ('script' === $node->nodeName) return '';

       $text = '';
       foreach($node->childNodes as $childNode) {
          $text .= extractText($childNode);
       }
       return $text;
     }
}
```

sample

```
 $Text=file_get_contents("http://inviatapenet.gethost.ro/sop/test1.php");
 preg_match_all('~fid="(.*?)"~si',$Text,$Match);
 $fid=$Match[1][1];
 echo $fid;
```

Comment: I put this Code but it gives me This new "%VAR_PLACE%"